# AWS Elasticbeanstalk application not deleting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to aws and having issues deleting an elasticbeanstalk application, it is empty and has no environments. when I use the console the button never becomes focused.[image: AWS console image]

When I tried using the was cloud shell, after running the delete command, I still see the application later
[image: AWS cloudshell image]

Comment: Did you delete all enviironments in the app first?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Go to Cloud Shell

- eb init
- Select a default region
- Select an application to use | The application you're trying to delete!
- Select a platform | Python for instance
- Select a platform branch | Python version in this case
- Do you want to set up SSH for your instances? (Y/n): n

Now you can delete all, by

- eb terminate --all --force

That's All!